# C# IF statement for a checkbox Value Points wont register into DB

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need help for my If Statement, at first it registers into the DB but only the value of 8, even if multiple values are tick. I know my if statements are wrong, but i have no idea what else to do. So should I remove the use another way if it's possible or I just messed a code up? I'm really bad at If's statement.

```
String points = null;
String ServiceCarWash = "Not Booked";
String ServiceCarPolish = "Not Booked";
String ServiceCarWax = "Not Booked";
int CustomerID = 0;

private void btnBook_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        connection.Open();
        String query = "INSERT into Booking ([Time],[Date],[CID],[VehicleNumber],[CarWash],[CarPolish],[CarWax])  VALUES('" + cmbTime.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + CustomerID + "','" + txtVn.Text + "','" + ServiceCarWash + "','" + ServiceCarPolish + "','" + ServiceCarWax + "')";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (CbCarwash.Checked)
        {
            ServiceCarWash = "Booked";
        }

        if (CbCarPolish.Checked)
        {
            ServiceCarPolish = "Booked";
        }

        if (CbCarWax.Checked)
        {
            ServiceCarWax = "Booked";
        }

        {
            if (txtMember.Text.Equals("VIP"))
            {
                if (ServiceCarPolish == "Booked")
                {
                    points = "20";
                }
                if (ServiceCarWash == "Booked")
                {
                    points = "2";
                }
                if (ServiceCarWax == "Booked")
                {
                    points = "8";
                }
            }
            else if (txtMember.Text.Equals("Walk-In"))
            {

                if (ServiceCarPolish == "Booked")
                {
                    points = "0";
                }
                if (ServiceCarWash == "Booked")
                {
                    points = "0";
                }
                if (ServiceCarWax == "Booked")
                {
                    points = "0";
                }
            }

            string query1 = "UPDATE *Customer set Points='" + points + "'";
            OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand(query1);
            command1.Connection = connection;
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Your time has been booked.");

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to accumulate points in code as per comments on previous question. See comments in the below and look out for the += signs.

```
//String points = null;
int points = 0;

String ServiceCarWash = "Not Booked";
String ServiceCarPolish = "Not Booked";
String ServiceCarWax = "Not Booked";
int CustomerID = 0;

private void btnBook_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        connection.Open();
        String query = "INSERT into Booking ([Time],[Date],[CID],[VehicleNumber],[CarWash],[CarPolish],[CarWax])  VALUES('" + cmbTime.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + CustomerID + "','" + txtVn.Text + "','" + ServiceCarWash + "','" + ServiceCarPolish + "','" + ServiceCarWax + "')";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query);
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (CbCarwash.Checked)
        {
            ServiceCarWash = "Booked";
        }

        if (CbCarPolish.Checked)
        {
            ServiceCarPolish = "Booked";
        }

        if (CbCarWax.Checked)
        {
            ServiceCarWax = "Booked";
        }

        {
            if (txtMember.Text.Equals("VIP"))
            {
                if (ServiceCarPolish == "Booked")
                {
                    points += 20;
                }
                if (ServiceCarWash == "Booked")
                {
                    points += 2;
                }
                if (ServiceCarWax == "Booked")
                {
                    points += 8;
                }
            }
            else if (txtMember.Text.Equals("Walk-In"))
            {

                if (ServiceCarPolish == "Booked")
                {
                    points += 0;
                }
                if (ServiceCarWash == "Booked")
                {
                    points += 0;
                }
                if (ServiceCarWax == "Booked")
                {
                    points += 0;
                }
            }

 //string query1 = "UPDATE *Customer set Points='" + points + "'";
            string query1 = "UPDATE *Customer set Points='" + points.ToString() + "'";
            OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand(query1);
            command1.Connection = connection;
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Your time has been booked.");

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But the problem left is that both Walk-In and VIP are generating the points. Please may I ask your help on this last part. How to specify the VIP is only able to record down those points.

Comment: Move the update command in to the bottom of the IF statement: if (txtMember.Text.Equals("VIP"))      then it will only run if the member is VIP

Comment: didn't work. Still the same, may I try it this way?
  string query1 = "UPDATE Customer set Points WHERE MemberType= 'VIP' '" + points + "'";

Comment: That may work if you never add points for Non-VIP. I have to leave you to it now, you are getting close, keep plugging at it and you will get there!

Comment: Well, I've changed my whole If statements, and it worked. Had to convert bits here and there into int, in order for it to work and only then string each of the value into the query. Later on adding each string, after confirming whether the checkbox are ticked or not.

Comment: Glad you finally got it sorted. Mark the answer as accepted or delete the question please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set your fields before inserting in to the database.

Move this code to the end of the method (or to just before the Customer update):

```
  connection.Open();
  String query = "INSERT into Booking ([Time],[Date],[CID],[VehicleNumber],[CarWash],[CarPolish],[CarWax])  VALUES('" + cmbTime.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + CustomerID + "','" + txtVn.Text + "','" + ServiceCarWash + "','" + ServiceCarPolish + "','" + ServiceCarWax + "')";
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query);
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, is *Customer the right table name, should it not just be Customer?

Check the value of your checkboxes to see if they are coming through correctly, then step through your IF's to make sure they calculate correctly. Refactoring in to smaller methods may help you break down the problem so that it is less complex and easier to work with.

Also check your brackets - you have some crazy stuff going on. See the second to last bracket below and you also have something weird going on a bit higher up with a bracket the wrong way around.

```
            else if (txtMember.Text.Equals("Walk-In"))
                {


                    if (ServiceCarPolish == "Booked")
                    {
                        points = "0";
                    }
                    if (ServiceCarWash == "Booked")
                    {
                        points = "0";
                    }
                    if (ServiceCarWax == "Booked")
                    {
                        points = "0";
                  }
                **{**
             }
```

Also make sure txtMember.Text always has a value so that points are set. Depending on your input, you can make your code a bit more robust by comparing tolower() in strings, e.g.: `txtMember.Text.ToLower().Equals("walk-in")`.

And step through with the debugger! :)

Comment: The booking is registering, the points aren't being updated in another table.

Comment: See my updated answer - is *Customer really the table name?

Comment: Nope, changed it already after I moved the query down to the bottom as you said. The Table name is Customer, under the Points Column Two types of members, Walk-In and a VIP just wanting to know how if the customer is a VIP the points will register into another table else, will remain as 0. Just in case if my question at first wasn't clear. Sorry.:- Code I meant.

Comment: Added more potential issues to the answer.

Comment: My txtMember.Text has a value. When a customer's detail is loaded, the customer would be a VIP or either a Walk-In already, so based on that the points will be added into the customers table for VIP only. =l (Side Note: My txtMember.Text reads from another table and displays the MemberType)

Comment: Step through with the debugger is all I can recommend now.

Comment: mm still the same problem. Points won't update in the other table. There aren't any errors.

Comment: Last trick to help you - Run up SQL profiler and make sure your update is coming through and what it's contents are.

Comment: Using MS Access, and I think I found the problem. It was registering, but my points aren't being set to the correct member now. Both are having the points.

Comment: Your update would be setting the points on all customers since there is no where clause. Glad you are making progress.

Comment: Do you have any recommended way on solving this. Last question, let me phrase it all up. Right now it's all set. Points are being set into the other table. But how do I accumulate the points , lets say in future, the user would book again. How do I accumulate the points and adding them up, along with setting that only VIP would have points recorded down and not walk-In? Sorry for asking too much. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Something like "Update Customer set Points =  Points + " + points To increment the points instead of replace them. Add a a where to the end in order to control your scope. E.g. "Update Customer set Points =  Points + " + points + "  where CustomerType = 'VIP'"

Comment: So I should change my Query to let's say :string query1 = "UPDATE Customer set Points = '"+ points +"','" +"' WHERE MemberType'" = 'VIP';

Comment: Close, just get rid of the comma, your final update statement should look like:  UPDATE Customer set Points = Points + 8 WHERE MemberType = 'VIP'

Comment: +8? I mean as in, if he checks lets say the first CheckBox, and second checkbox. Both those values will be added together and put into the column table. Then in future same thing, those points will be added again with the previous points.

Comment: Ah, you want to accumulate in the code and not in the DB. I'll add another answer with that in it for you.